# Low resolution stuck aften pressing win+p, what does win+p do?

Tags: shortcut-keys, screen, display-resolution

My screen resolution got stuck after I pressed <kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>p</kbd>. I don't know what that key combination does and would like to find out? I've looked at setting -> Keyboard -> shortcuts.
To resolve the resolution issue, I've simply disconnected the monitor from the device, reset the device and then connected the monitor back to the device.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So pressing `Win`-`P` enables Mirror displays, which in the settings and Display section it says: Note: may limit resolution options. I did it to test it and it took all screens to 1080, normally they are 2K or 4K.

Comment: Yeah, how did you find out what it does? The issue is that when I disabled the mirror displays, the resolution was still limited. Interesting.

Comment: The way I found out was I press the button and then I looked in the display section of the settings and noticed the Mirror displays was checked. When unchecking it I had to set the resolution again, as it was still 1080 for all of my monitors.